# Raspberry: "do-release-upgrade" thinks 'Jammy Jellyfish' is still in development

Tags: upgrade, raspberrypi, 22.04

I wish to upgrade my Raspberry to Jammy Jellyfish. It was released yesterday and announced in news.

But on my machine it still shows that's beta release!

```
# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=impish
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.10"


# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.

# do-release-upgrade -p -m server
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.

# do-release-upgrade -c -m server
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.

# do-release-upgrade -c -m server --allow-third-party
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.

# date
Sat Apr 23 07:49:28 CEST 2022

# do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release

= Welcome to the Ubuntu 'Jammy Jellyfish' development release =

''This release is still in development.''

Thanks for your interest in this development release of Ubuntu.
The Ubuntu developers are moving very quickly to bring you the
absolute latest and greatest software the Open Source Community has to
offer. This development release brings you a taste of the newest features
for the next version of Ubuntu.

== Testing ==

Please help to test this development snapshot and report problems back to the
developers.  For more information about testing Ubuntu, please read:

  http://www.ubuntu.com/testing


== Reporting Bugs ==

This development release of Ubuntu contains bugs. If you want to help
out with bugs, the Bug Squad is always looking for help. Please read the
following information about reporting bugs
```

Is this some raspberry specific bug?

I did

```
apt update && apt upgrade && apt dist-upgrade && apt autoremove && apt install update-manager-core
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It takes until after the first point release (22.04.1) for `do-release-upgrade` to become available for general use. This is usually in August.

Some years, when there have been known problems, the team has held back the availability of an update through `do-release-upgrade` for a long time, until the issues are ironed out. This can be particularly so if you're on the LTS-to-LTS track.

Answer (score 4):

There are currently some issues with upgrading from 21.10 to 22.04. That is why `do-release-upgrade` is showing jammy as a development release. If you want to take the risk and go ahead with the installation use the -d switch, but I would recommend waiting until the issues are solved.

The release date is the date when the iso is available for download. Upgrades from non-LTS releases may take a few more days and for LTS to LTS upgrades, Ubuntu releases the upgrade after the first point release (22.04.1) three months after release.

I've seen people reporting upgrading from 21.10 and end up with the system not booting, so it's better to be patient…

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message 'This release is still in development.' but was also prompted to continue.  I said "y"and my machine is currently upgrading.

Comment: You may want to add more info about how it went to make your answer more useful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Linux expert, however, you should use `do-release-upgrade` without the `-d` flag. `-d` flag is for the development version.

I did the same and it's currently upgrading!

Comment: without the `-d` he not finds a release. See posting. `Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.`